# CSS arranging two full width divs bellow each other

Tags: css

I have two divs whose css looks like following:

```
.div-one:before {
  content: "";
  background: url("../../../assets/images/manhattan-min.png") center no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.div-one {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.div-five{
  position: relative;
  background-color: brown;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

I basically want to design it as a typical landing page, the div-one is full sized image that occupies entire screen and as user scrolls down he can see another full screen div-five which is more or less where I can show some product details. Right now, with this css :before part renders in such a way that there is horizontal scrollbar.

**UPDATE:**

```
.div-two {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  -webkit-animation: left-to-right-div2 0.2s forwards;
  animation: left-to-right-div2 0.2s forwards;
}
.div-three {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  -webkit-animation: left-to-right-div3 0.2s forwards;
  animation: left-to-right-div3 0.2s forwards;
}
.div-four {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  -webkit-animation: left-to-right-div3 0.2s forwards;
  animation: left-to-right-div3 0.2s forwards;
}
```

div-two, div-three,div-four basically open with 50% width where the div-one is.

Comment: What happened to `.div-two` through `.div-four`?

Comment: Those I render conditionally. I will update my question with their css as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `display` property:

```
.div-one:before {
  content: "";
  background: url("../../../assets/images/manhattan-min.png") center no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}

.div-one {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}

.div-five{
  position: relative;
  background-color: brown;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

This should position all the `div` elements below each other on the web page

Comment: I didn't change anything for me :( I have updated question with another divs, perhaps that can have impact

Comment: @Nitish just to clarify which `div`s must be rendered below each other?

Comment: div-one and div-five. other divs open with 50% width where div-one is.

Comment: @Nitish this is actually very weird behavior a a `div` element generally renders by default to have a block display. Have you tried using Bootstrap. Their grid system also works great for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Sure I will try. Wanted to stick to pure css actually.